# Есть ли быстрые библиотеки для Python для нечеткого поиска? Расстояние Левенштейна

Tags: python, c++, поиск, поиск-библиотек, нечеткий-поиск

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли быстрые библиотеки для Python для нечеткого поиска? Мне требуется найти позицию участка в тексте наиболее близкого к заданному патерну.

Сейчас использую реализацию из этой статьи: https://habr.com/ru/post/279585
Проблема в том, что поиск очень медленный и хотелось бы его значительно ускорить. Поэтому я ищу библиотеку написанную на C++. Но все что я нахожу просто выводит к-т схожести двух текстов, но не выдает позицию наиболее похожего фрагмента текста.

Comment: А Левенштейн вам действительно помогает? На практике там слишком много ошибок как первого, так и второго рода. А вообще попробуйте библиотеку `fuzzysearch`. Ну и хорошо бы в целом расписать use case - что ищете, в чём, сколько у вас этих поисков (миллионы?)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте библиотеку [fuzzysearch](https://github.com/taleinat/fuzzysearch), там есть Левенштейн и вроде бы она достаточно оптимизированная. Как и большинство библиотек `Python` она использует внутри `C` и `Cython`.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё есть оптимизированное расстояние Левенштейна в библиотеке `editdistance`:

https://pypi.org/project/editdistance/0.3.1/